# Can I use module pool to decide load balance?

Tags: erlang

I'm looking for an automatic way to do my load balance and this module attracted me.

As the manual says,

> pool can be used to run a set of Erlang nodes as a pool of computational processors. 
>   It is organized as a master and a set of slave nodes and includes the following features:
>
> - The slave nodes send regular reports to the master about their current load.
> - Queries can be sent to the master to determine which node will have the least load.
>
> The BIF statistics(run_queue) is used for estimating future loads. 
>   It returns the length of the queue of ready to run processes in the Erlang runtime system.

What's the frequency and load for the slave nodes to send regular reports?

Is it a proper way to make load balance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reports are sent [every 2 seconds](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint/lib/stdlib/src/pool.erl#l218) and use information gathered from `statistics(run_queue)` to determine the node with the least load. `run_queue` returns the queue size of the current node's scheduler.

When you call `pool:get_node/0` you are getting the node with the lowest number of tasks waiting to be executed on it's scheduler. Keep in mind that nodes are kept in sorted order so calls to `pool:get_node/0` do not directly query nodes, but rather rely on information that could be up to 2 seconds old.

If you need a load balanced pool of nodes, `pool` works great.

Here is some more info from the pool.erl source:

```
%% Supplies a computational pool of processors.
%% The chief user interface function here is get_node()
%% Which returns the name of the nodes in the pool
%% with the least load !!!!
%% This function is callable from any node including the master
%% That is part of the pool
%% nodes are scheduled on a per usgae basis and per load basis,
%% Whenever we use a node, we put at the end of the queue, and whenever
%% a node report a change in load, we insert it accordingly
```